# Access other script Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script called `Move` in c# in unity, and I have a variable called `life` inside of it.

I want to access this variable and change it from another script, so I use (as the documentation says):

```
OtherScript enemy = GetComponent<Move>();
```

and then:

```
enemy.life = enemy.life - 25;
```

But this give me the error, as below:

> The type or namespace name `OtherScript' could not be found. Are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then, if your script is called move, it should be

```
Move enemy = GetComponent<Move>();
```